# Exportar query node.js para HTML

Tags: node.js

Estou iniciando em Node.js e fiz um Crud, e estou tentando retornar uma query para minha pagina inicial, mas não achei documentação para guardar este count e levar para la. (Preferi não utilizar o `sequelize` inicialmente).

Já consigo ter o valor no log.

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){

        sql.query({sql: 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM clientes where idstatus="Critico"'}, function (err, criticos) {
            console.log(criticos[0].count + ' Criticos');
            });

           sql.query({sql: 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM clientes where idstatus="Em Implantação"'}, function (err, emimp) {
           console.log(emimp[0].count + ' Em Implantação');
           });

          sql.query({sql: 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM clientes where idstatus="Paralisado"'}, function (err, paral) {
          console.log(paral[0].count + ' Pralisados');
           });

           sql.query({sql: 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM clientes where idstatus="Não iniciado"'}, function (err, naoini) {
           console.log(naoini[0].count + ' Não iniciados');
           });



    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Você deve preencher o response e envia-lo para os resultados serem retornados pela API.

Modifique seu código para ficar assim:

```
app.get("/",function(req,res){

var queryResults = [];

        sql.query({sql: 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM clientes where idstatus="Critico"'}, function (err, criticos) {
            console.log(criticos[0].count + ' Criticos');
            queryResults.push(criticos);
            });

           sql.query({sql: 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM clientes where idstatus="Em Implantação"'}, function (err, emimp) {
           console.log(emimp[0].count + ' Em Implantação');
            queryResults.push(emimp);

           });

          sql.query({sql: 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM clientes where idstatus="Paralisado"'}, function (err, paral) {
          console.log(paral[0].count + ' Pralisados');
            queryResults.push(paral);

           });

           sql.query({sql: 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM clientes where idstatus="Não iniciado"'}, function (err, naoini) {
           console.log(naoini[0].count + ' Não iniciados');
            queryResults.push(naoini);

           });

           res.send(queryResults);

    });
```